# Why I am this Error in decoding JSON Web Token Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, jwt, authorization

I have a key named `social-public.key`, which I am using to decode JWTs, but the problem is I am having an error as below

```
Error occurred while decoding access token Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
    at Verify.verify (internal/crypto/sig.js:157:24)
    at Object.verify (D:\SocialAnalysisDashboard\social-dashboard-user-service\node_modules\jwa\index.js:164:21)
    at Object.jwsVerify [as verify] (D:\SocialAnalysisDashboard\social-dashboard-user-service\node_modules\jws\lib\verify-stream.js:54:15)
    at D:\SocialAnalysisDashboard\social-dashboard-user-service\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:127:19
    at getSecret (D:\SocialAnalysisDashboard\social-dashboard-user-service\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:90:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (D:\SocialAnalysisDashboard\social-dashboard-user-service\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:94:10)
    at D:\SocialAnalysisDashboard\social-dashboard-user-service\express\Middlewares\auth.js:24:46
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  library: 'PEM routines',
  function: 'get_name',
  reason: 'no start line',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE'
}
```

Here is code the code I am using to decode JWTs,

```
const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, key, {algorithms: ['RS256']});
```

Mostly solutions I have found are related to `.pem` files.

Comment: there are already many questions and answers regarding this error, I guess you might find a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=error%3A0909006C%3APEM+routines%3Aget_name%3Ano+start+line

Comment: @jps as I mentioned I tried but they related to `.pem` file, while I'm using `.key` file

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I fixed it with help of [this](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/400) issue post. You only need one key to sign and verify if you use `HS256`. The `RSA` version requires a public and private key (Public for verification and private for signing)

Follow the following steps:

1. Have a valid public and it's associated private key. ([csfieldguide](http://www.csfieldguide.org.nz/en/interactives/rsa-key-generator/index.html), [travistidwell](http://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/demo/))
2. Include the '---private/public key start---' and '---public/private key end---' part
3. I saved it in `base64` and can be giving directly in the `jsonwebtoken` module from `npm`
4. Make sure the new line byte (`\n`) is giving with the `base64` string

example:

```
let secret = [
        '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----',
        'MIIBVAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAT4wggE6AgEAAkEAkcd7iupXSHhgIRat',
        'b2gnEiyC3AIf7GCrISTtgM5Lb8kccGjunU8sIqwwd3BV6qD+pExeyvMyU085RHRX',
        'ud1cyQIDAQABAkAzmni6GPAiwDHPJLbqK+VAwq7j8ICabTHGvsqwANalT/O4V75m',
        'e2ExeqV05+jlzVOGrQ953n8Mx1u0uRgPlfoBAiEAyO3qytGKRRzlqBuGwPFPde4a',
        '66ZW4AmRcBwwuKp1zgkCIQC5u/2j/JFzM4GTbpoC0a2u78+tqYQW7Y/Usu6AAubI',
        'wQIhAMKbhMQJ7UUBNwH6HyryzcZn5pUEl7IIMmAGPb4uA0mZAiAbJPhawQzY00w6',
        'qc1kYBSMHowxiza8yxdcNJJarxHfgQIgcw2oEtn8GbvNMOsFg0Q9TPMdQ+uhxhWK',
        'xhVgWkIkTVU=',
        '-----END PRIVATE KEY-----',
    ].join('\n');
```

Same goes for the public key when verifying.

```
// Create a signed JWT token
const token = jwt.sign(payload, privKey, {algorithm: 'RS256', ...otherSignOptions}); 

// returns undefined if token could not be verified
jwt.verify(token, pubKey);
```

I'd recommend of course reading the key from a file instead of hardcoding it. (preferably in a safe location)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

async function verifyAzureADIdToken(idToken) {
  try {
    // Step 1: Retrieve OIDC configuration
    const oidcConfigUrl = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/.well-known/openid-configuration';
    const oidcConfigResponse = await axios.get(oidcConfigUrl);
    const jwksUri = oidcConfigResponse.data.jwks_uri;

    // Step 2: Retrieve JWKS (JSON Web Key Set)
    const jwksResponse = await axios.get(jwksUri);
    const jwks = jwksResponse.data;

    // Step 3: Find the key matching the token's Key ID (kid)
    const tokenHeader = jwt.decode(idToken, { complete: true }).header;
    const matchingKey = jwks.keys.find(key => key.kid === tokenHeader.kid);

    // Step 4: Verify the ID token using the public key
    const publicKey = `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n${matchingKey.x5c[0]}\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----`;

    const verifiedToken = jwt.verify(idToken, publicKey);
    console.log('ID token verification succeeded:', verifiedToken);
    return verifiedToken;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('ID token verification failed:', error.message);
    throw error;
  }
}

// Usage example:
const idToken = 'YOUR_AZURE_AD_ID_TOKEN';

verifyAzureADIdToken(idToken);
```

// NOTE: here you need entier public key not just kid you extracted
// from jwt, from that we extract x5c - base64 encoded values

Comment: Also note that here you need entire public key from jwksResponse not just kid

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer contains code without explanation. It's better to include details about *how* your answer answers the question.